# Should WebClient be used in a using statement?

Tags: c#, httpclient, webclient, using

If HttpClient is not supposed to be used in a **using** statement, see these links:
https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/
http://www.nimaara.com/2016/11/01/beware-of-the-net-httpclient/

So if your not supposed to use HttpClient in a using statement then why do so many examples out there put WebClient in a using statement (including Microsoft); also I have not yet seen an article about not putting WebClient in a **using** statement? Eventually at the lowest level both WebClient and HttpClient end up at the same place opening a TCP/IP socket. Is it what's in-between that makes WebClient acceptable to put in a **using** statement?

Note I have a reason for asking this question: I have a client application that runs on WinXP, Win7 full and embedded systems, the code that I use to POST XML to my backend host (CentOS system) looks like this:

```
void PostXml(string url, string xml, int id) {
    try
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("POST Request: " + xml);
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Proxy = null;    //DEBUG: testing this to see if it helps webclient post failure after time x
            wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            Byte[] d = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);

            //however Async below is better regardless for closing app and non interference with GUI
            //Byte[] res = web.UploadData(url, "POST", d);  //sychrounous will block until sent and response returned

            wc.UploadDataCompleted += new UploadDataCompletedEventHandler(web_UploadDataCompleted);
            wc.UploadDataAsync(new Uri(url), "POST", d, id);
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        string responseText = "";
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        string logMsg = DateTime.Now.ToString("s") + " - PostXml WebClient webexception: " + ex.Message + "\r\n" +
            "  response: " + responseText + "\r\n\r\n";
        File.AppendAllText(SPUClient.frmMain._logFile, logMsg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        //Console.WriteLine("PostXml Exception: " + ex.Message);
        string logMsg = DateTime.Now.ToString("s") + " - PostXml exception: " + ex.Message + "\r\n";
        File.AppendAllText(SPUClient.frmMain._logFile, logMsg);
    }
}
```

PostXml is called 2 times every 1 minute, I have 400 clients in the field that run this code above, some of them have run for more than a year with no errors. But we have had a few clients that run this code after running for several weeks, or several months just stop doing the UploadDataAsync( "POST" ) evidently? All we know at this time is we don't get an exception, the POST message does not leave the computer and on my CentOS log file I can see that it never arrived (the domain.net.access.log on CentOS shows all the POST connections from all my clients). Remember this rarely happens some clients have never failed, some run for months / weeks before this happens. Restarting the client application fixes the problem of course. Should I be using WebClient in a using statement could that be the cause of something like this issue or is it something else?

Comment: If there ever was an "it depends" scenario, it is this one.

Comment: This seems unlikely to be correct usage given that you are disposing before the async operation is completed. Also the errors would probably appear in the arguments to the event handler not in this method.

Comment: @mikez - are you saying that I should probably not be putting WebClient in a using statement - but like I say my code works fine for long periods of time and some clients that run this code have never failed? It seems to me that WebClient is getting disposed probably way before the async callback function is hit but it works. I can debug it in VS2015 and it always hits the callback correctly.

Comment: @mikez - also I do examine EventArgs e.Error in the callback function web_UploadDataCompleted and have a try catch in it to log Exceptions. However I did just add logging if e.Error is not null so maybe I'll see something if this happens again?

Comment: Actually looking at the code for WebClient I see that it is derived from Component and this is where Dispose comes from. WebClient itself does not seem to use this and in fact you can Dispose a WebClient instance and continue to make calls with it so I suspect the any concern about `using` is a red herring.