# WebException when calling WebClient.CancelAsync on "await DownloadTaskAsync"

Tags: c#, async-await, webclient

This works fine:

```
private WebClient _webClient;

private void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    using (_webClient = new WebClient()) {
        _webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync("https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin", @"D:\100MB.bin");
    }
}

private void ButtonStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    _webClient.CancelAsync();
}
```

While this code (notice the async/await pattern)...:

```
private WebClient _webClient;

private async void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    using (_webClient = new WebClient()) {
        await _webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync("https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin", @"D:\100MB.bin");
    }
}

private void ButtonStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    _webClient.CancelAsync();
}
```

... throws the following exception:

> **System.Net.WebException**
>
> The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

```
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsReadCallbackState(DownloadBitsState state, IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at WpfApp1.MainWindow.<ButtonStart_Click>d__2.MoveNext() in WpfApp1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 19
```

How can I cancel a task started with `await WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync()` without throwing an exception?

Comment: How would you know the download was aborted?

Comment: I doubt that first block of code really works fine: you'll be disposing the `_webClient` almost instantly, which means it's probably disposed by the time `CancelAsync()` gets called. I'd guess that CancelAsync is returning an error in a Task which you're ignoring because you're not awaiting it. So it appears to work fine, but the request isn't actually getting canceled.

Comment: @PauloMorgado By checking the `AsyncCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled` status in the `WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted` event handler.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Well the download is stopped, that surely means the request is cancelled, isn't it?

Comment: @Otiel: Touché. I was just thinking your download shouldn't complete when the request _isn't_ canceled. Normally if you have a `using` statement and neglect to await async tasks you'll get burned for it. But based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52787178/should-webclient-be-used-in-a-using-statement#comment92496419_52787178) and [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/System/Net/webclient.cs), `WebClient` basically ignores getting disposed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception is exactly how it's *supposed* to work.

If you don't want that exception propagating out of your event handler, then catch the exception.

Answer (score 3):

You can catch the exception like this:

```
using (_webClient = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        await _webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync("https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin", @"D:\100MB.bin");
    }
    catch (WebException ex) when (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** How to change the default behavior of `CancelAsync`, to avoid having to catch an exception:

```
public static Task<bool> OnCancelReturnTrue(this Task task)
{
    return task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted)
        {
            if (t.Exception.InnerException is WebException webEx
                && webEx.Status == WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled) return true;
            throw t.Exception;
        }
        return t.IsCanceled;
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
}
```

Usage example:

```
bool cancelled = await _webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(
    "https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin", @"D:\100MB.bin").OnCancelReturnTrue();
if (cancelled) Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
```

Comment: Thanks. That's already what I'm doing, just wanted to know if there was a cleaner way to cancel the task without throwing an exception.

Comment: @Otiel it throws exception by design. Apparently cancellation is perceived as something exceptional. If you want to get fancy you could concoct some custom extension method to change this behavior to your likings. I have updated my answer with an example.